# Updating variable in bash script

Tags: bash

I have a collections of scripts I am calling with a wrapper script. I want to update the $date variable each time it is call in the wrapper.

Current code:

```
start=$(date "+%m-%d-%Y-%T")
echo "Begin Executing Update Jobs at $start"

update1.sh
datetime1=$(date "+%m-%d-%Y-%T")
echo "Executed update 1 - $datetime1"

update2.sh
datetime2=$(date "+%m-%d-%Y-%T")
echo "Executed update 2 - $datetime2"

update3.sh
datetime3=$(date "+%m-%d-%Y-%T")
echo "Executed update 3 - $datetime3"

finish=$(date "+%m-%d-%Y-%T")
echo "Finished Execution at $finish"
```

Is there a better way to do this than calling the date every time to update it?

Comment: Use a function. See `help function`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend writing a reusable function.  It looks like all of your lines print a message and then a timestamp.  Let's create a function a function that takes the message as an argument (`$1`), and then prints a timestamp like this:

```
function printdate {
  echo "$1 $(date "+%m-%d-%Y-%T")"
}
```

Then you could have a line that says

```
printdate "Executed update 3 -"
```

and it would print

```
Executed update 3 - 08-14-2020-11:48:42
```

Comment: `printf '%s - %(%m-%d-%Y-%T)T\n' "$1"` would do same and lighter.

Comment: That did it! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Alternate method using a format string for `printf`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# shellcheck disable=SC2059 # Using variable format strings

declare -r _DATEFMT='%(%m-%d-%Y-%T)T'
declare -r _MSGATFMT="%s at $_DATEFMT\n"
declare -r _UPDATEFMT="Executed update %d - $_DATEFMT\n"

printf "$_MSGATFMT" 'Begin Executing Update Jobs'

for ((upd=1; upd<=3; upd++)); do
  "update$upd.sh"
  printf "$_UPDATEFMT" "$upd"
done

printf "$_MSGATFMT" 'Finished Execution'
```